# jQuery .on with .get methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the tag name of the element clicked inside an `li` when the user clicks on the element. The `li` element is added dynamically to the HTML code. To do this I am using the code below however it does not seem to be working.

```
$('li *','div#contentWrapper').on('click','#interfaceContainer #left #sortableTestComponents li',function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        var domEl = $(this).get(0);
        alert(domEl.tagName);
        if(!$(event.target).hasClass("deleteTestComp")){
            var type = $(this).find('div.headerName').html();
            var information = $(this).find('input[type=hidden]').val();

            if(type == "CliSessionType"){
                 parseCliComponent(information);
            }
            else if(type == "DBSessionType"){
                parseDbComponent(information);
            }
            else{
                parseScreenComponent(information);
            }
        }
    });
```

Why is my code not working? Nothing happens when the user clicks on an element.

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/3FxQE/

Comment: Can you show us a working example?

Comment: Or show some representative markup that you are working with?

Comment: Created a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/3FxQE/

Comment: your code seems to indicate that you have at least 7 levels between div#contentWrapper and the clicked li. Is it the case? Posting the html would help.

Comment: Yes that is the case, the HTML is in the JSFiddle, do you want all the HTML as there is a lot.

Comment: Colin747, you cannot attach a handler on a non-exiting element with `on`. You apply `on` on a parent of the element which is to be dynamically created. In your particular case, if you are dynamically creating `li`'s , then attach `on` on `ul`

Comment: Everything under contentWrapper is being dynamically created

Comment: why do you want to have the `tagName` of the clicked element

Comment: @Colin747 sorry, I completely missed the jsfiddle link :-( You had your selectors in the wrong order (as already answered...) and the li is not the 7th level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are interested in `click` events in `li` elements which comes under `#interfaceContainer`, the event registration must be `$('#interfaceContainer').on('click','li',function(e){...});`

Then to get the `tagName`, you need to use the actual source of the event this is available in `e.target` so you need to use `$(e.target).get(0)` to get the clicked dom element.

```
$('#interfaceContainer').on('click','li',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    var domEl = $(e.target).get(0);
    alert(domEl.tagName);
    if(!$(event.target).hasClass("deleteTestComp")){
        var type = $(this).find('div.headerName').html();
        var information = $(this).find('input[type=hidden]').val();

        if(type == "CliSessionType"){
             parseCliComponent(information);
        }
        else if(type == "DBSessionType"){
            parseDbComponent(information);
        }
        else{
            parseScreenComponent(information);
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/UZDPe/)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a context where you don't need to, in your selector. Change `$('li *','div#contentWrapper')` with `$('div#contentWrapper')` and `$(event.target)` with `$(e.target)`. A working fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3FxQE/2/)

```
$('div#contentWrapper').on('click', '#interfaceContainer #left #sortableTestComponents li', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var $this = $(this),
        domEl = $this.get(0);
    alert(domEl.tagName);
    if (!$(e.target).hasClass("deleteTestComp")) {
        var type = $this.find('div.headerName').html(),
            information = $this.find('input[type=hidden]').val();

        if (type == "CliSessionType") {
            parseCliComponent(information);
        } else if (type == "DBSessionType") {
            parseDbComponent(information);
        } else {
            parseScreenComponent(information);
        }
    }
});
```